# Where's LockablePivot?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-toolkit

I've pulled the Windows Phone Control Toolkit via NuGet into my WinPhone8 project. The LockablePivot control that was [advertised as being a part of the toolkit since August 2011](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-toolkit-lockablepivot-in-depth) isn't there. What's its fate, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was removed from the WP8 SDK because WP8 `Pivot` has an "isLocked" property. See [this link](http://phone.codeplex.com/workitem/10577)

You can even see in your link it's tagged `WP7Toolkit`